# E2E_CONTEXT namespace used in setClientInfo in Oracle's implementation of the JDBC 4.1 standard

Tags: oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

What does the `E2E_CONTEXT` namespace in [Oracle's implementation of the JDBC 4.1 standard](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/jdbc-developers-guide.pdf) mean? Where is it defined? Where can I find all defined namespaces? Can I define my own namespaces and if so, how?

Comment: I'm not sure, Oracle often introduces some super cool half-cooked feature. Which is then forgotten because is it barely documented. setClientInfo() as introduced to set columns ACTION, MODULE in v$session view. So DBAs can see relation between a particular SQL and application's module.  In this case I'd say that DBOP stands for database operation and has something to do with DBMS_MONITOR. A detailed performance monitoring tool. Part of Oracle Tunning pack license.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace `E2E_CONTEXT` is now internal to Oracle and shouldn't be used. It was created to support end-to-end tracing but was quickly replaced by the more complete `OCSID` namespace which can be used to set the following attributes:

- ACTION
- MODULE
- CLIENTID
- ECID
- DBOP

using the JDBC standard [setClientInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#setClientInfo(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) method. These attributes are then propagated to views like V$MYSTAT, V$SESSION, V$SQL, etc.  There is another built-in namespace called `CLIENTCONTEXT` that can be used to store custom key value pairs (see example below).

You can't use your own namespace through Oracle JDBC.

```
con.setClientInfo('OCSID.CLIENTID','my Client ID');
con.setClientInfo('OCSID.MODULE','my Module');
con.setClientInfo('OCSID.ACTION','my Action');
con.setClientInfo('CLIENTCONTEXT.MyKey', 'MyValue);
```